# SceneKit didApplyAnimationsAtTime calculation time

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Hi I'm trying to compute the time it takes to my renderer to run the actions and animations.
From what I understand here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate

The time property in rendererDiDSomething: time should be different in each callback provided your game takes time to render on screen.

I have a complex scene with rigged animations, I can see using the SceneView statistics that the animation are taking a lot each frame. But when I check the time property in the callback they are all the same.
I also tried to compute time difference between frames and it's always 0.0

What am I missing here?

Snippet to illustrate:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    print(time)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didApplyAnimationsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    print(time)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
    print(time)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all SceneKit's `renderer()` instance methods having `time` argument show us the same values due to a fact this time is a system time (expressed in seconds and milliseconds) presented by `TimeInterval` type alias of Double class.

It seems that we have no possibility in this API to find out what a **sub-frame time** in render loop is, like a time when evaluation of constraints is precisely occurred, or when an animation was applied.

Comment: Hi ARGeo, that's an interesting response, Apple is giving us those callbacks so we can update any logic at those key moments in a frame. 
They take care of sending this logic to the engine but we cannot know any further. That makes more sense now. Time is the frame time not a **sub-frame time** at those key moments.
That should be the accepted answer, thank you!

Comment: I suppose `time` argument is mainly for comparison. But render loop's logic itself is inside each render() method (I mean `before...`, `after...`, etc).